# Hiding the presentation controls in LaTeX beamer presentation

Tags: latex, presentation, beamer

I am currently building a presentation using LaTeX beamer. Is there a way to hide the presentation controls on the bottom of the slides? I don't use those controls, and they sometimes collide with the slide's text.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Yes, from p.223 of [the Beamer guide](http://faq.ktug.or.kr/wiki/uploads/beamer_guide.pdf):

> To remove navigation symbols,
>
> \usenavigationsymbolstemplate{}

Although it looks like the syntax has changed since then. [This more recent page](http://stuffforlife.blogspot.com/2008/10/logo-in-latex-beamer-presentation.html) has:

```
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}%remove navigation symbols
```

Answer (score 65):

The simplest way is:

```
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
```

Comment: ThatisagoodanswerthanyouverymuchIwillupvoteitnow

Comment: @WaldirLeoncio Lacking a »k«? (won't compile ;) )