# How to get rid of navigation bars in beamer?

Tags: latex, pdflatex, presentation, beamer, lyx

How can I remove the navigation bar of sections and subsections on the top of each slide generated from a beamer latex file?

I'm using the package beamerthemesplit.

Comment: There is a proposed site at Area51 for questions like this: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2148/tex-latex-and-friends?referrer=5z6F4dAmVScN5QfMOt5KEg2 (disclaimer: link includes my referral ID)

Comment: @David: and some meta discussion http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12918/can-we-have-a-ruling-on-latex-on-stackoverflow.  LaTeX posts are welcome on SO.

Comment: @Mark: Yes, I know, but the Area51 proposal is a better place for this type of question. I'm leaving a "forwarding address" so to speak, so that people who stumble on to this question later on will know that there's another place they could ask their own questions.

Comment: @David, I'm not sure I follow.  If folks want to get answers to LaTeX questions, SO is a perfectly reasonable place to come get them.

Comment: Please try and make your question title reflect the content of your question. "Beamer latex question" is not a good title. "How to get rid of navigation bars in beamer" is a good title.

Comment: @Mark: The LaTeX SE2.0 site, whenever it opens, will be a better place to get those answers, because that's where the experts will be. Or think about it this way: if LaTeX questions really should be asked here, what is the point of having another site devoted to them, and why have more than 250 people expressed their support for it? I agree that _currently_ LaTeX questions are fair game on SO, but once the other site opens, that could/should change.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide presentation controls in LaTeX beamer presentation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017030/hide-presentation-controls-in-latex-beamer-presentation)

Comment: @Seamus: I edited the question title for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get rid of navigation bars in beamer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210205/how-to-get-rid-of-navigation-bars-in-beamer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stupid way to make sure the presentation structure does not show up, (independent of theme)  comment out the `\section` and `\subsection` commands.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to remove the section navigation at the top of the frame is to change the headline template.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\useoutertheme{split}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}

\begin{document}

\section{title}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Beamer has different themes you can use, some of which include that navigation bar and some of which don't. The default theme, for example, doesn't include any navigation bar. All the themes available with Beamer are described in the [user guide](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf); just pick one that suits your requirements and use it:

```
\usetheme{default}
```

for example.

If you want to alter an existing theme to remove the navigation bar, you can try setting

```
\useoutertheme{default}
```

and see if that gives you a look you like. If not, you'll probably have to get into some theme-specific manipulations. The information needed to do this is in the user guide I linked to above.

Comment: David, I tried that, but the navigation bar is still there. The preamble I wrote is: \usepackage{beamerthemesplit} \setbeamercovered{transparent} \useoutertheme{default} \usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}

Comment: That's because you are trying to use three different outer themes. Only the last one, in your case `shadow`, will actually be in effect. You should remove `\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}` and `\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}` and only leave `\useoutertheme{default}`. (Also keep in mind that `\usepackage` is the wrong way to use a Beamer theme)

Comment: David, thanks for your answer, but I want to keep the shadow effect and the color of the background. By removing \usepackage{beamerthemesplit} and \usepackage{beamerthemeshadow} and only leave \useoutertheme{default}, I don't have the shadow effect and the color of the background anymore, although the the navigation bar is removed. Do you have any other idea on this?

Comment: For that kind of fine-grained modification, you can use the theme but you'll have to override an individual Beamer template. I took a look at the source files that define the shadow template, and I _think_ you'll need to insert something like `\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}` after `\useoutertheme{shadow}` (and of course you should remove `\useoutertheme{default}`). But I'm not familiar with the process of modifying these templates, so you may need to examine the theme definitions yourself in connection with the Beamer user guide to figure out how to get the look you want.