# How to get rid of navigation bars in beamer

Tags: latex, pdflatex, beamer

How to remove the navigation bar of sections and subsections on the top of each slide generated from a beamer latex file?

By the way, in my preamble, I wrote:

```
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
```

Comment: Did you try switching the two lines?

Comment: @Mark : a duplicate of his own question! :) I guess he didn't get the answer he wanted then, and decided to try again...

Answer (score 134, accepted):

I don't know whether this is what you want, but if you are talking about the navigation bar which has the symbols you can click on, this is the way to go:

```
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
```

Funny, that is the [second time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183258/beamer-latex-question) you ask this....

By the way, you might want to check [this](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2148/tex-latex-and-friends?referrer=7gADB5n9I0qU41zfK7oIpw2) proposal for a question/answer website focusing on LaTeX.

Comment: I put it immediately after `\begin{document}` and it works.

Answer (score 9):

The section navigation at the top of the frame is part of the headline. The easiest way to remove it is to change the headline template.

The line `\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}` is unrelated to the sections in the headline, this will remove the little symbols at the bottom right if the frame.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\useoutertheme{shadow}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}

\begin{document}

\section{title}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```